# How to record audio in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am doing a loopback test in android, which record's audio using AudioRecorder then encode the uncompressed pcm into speex after that   i  decode  speex back to pcm and given  to AudioPlayer for playing .Later case i will test between two devices P2P . I am trying to record audio , similar to call  recording in which save both sender and receiver voide into a single file mp4 format .Can anybody suggest me a good direction to proceed   and also is it possible to achieve this through ffmpeg  ported for android?

thanks,

Answer (score 4):

i hope it will work for you..
set your path in" this.path = sanitizePath(path); in this line"

```
    public class AudioRecorder
    {
    final MediaRecorder recorder=new MediaRecorder();
    final String path;

    public AudioRecorder(String path) 
        {
        this.path = sanitizePath(path);
        }
private String sanitizePath(String path) 
    {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) 
        {
      path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains("."))   
        {
      path += ".3gp";
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
 }
public void start() throws IOException 
    {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
}
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) 
        {
      throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
  }
 public void stop() throws IOException 
     {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
 }
```

}

Comment: This will record the audio from mic source i.e sender voice But the audio that i receive from a remote end point is routed to headset which is a decoded PCM from speex data whether your solution will record the received audio also inside a single file ? I prefer mp4a format

Comment: i cant get your proper question pls mention in detail what u want?and waht to do in your application@newentry

Comment: have to record  both sender and receiver audio into single file mp4a as i explained before.

Answer (score 0):

MediaRecorder.AudioSource is a good start I guess?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html